# Writing anonymous function in jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Please help me to write the anonymous function in animation, I have given the code which I have tried, Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/72V8k/), I want to know how to write the anonymous function in animation like what I did in the Css button click, thank in advance

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <style type="text/css">
           #example{width:100px;height:100px;background: #F00;}
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#check').click(function(){
                    $('#example').css({width:function(){
                            console.log($(this).width());
                            return $(this).width()=="0"? "100":"0";
                    }});
                });
                $('#animate').click(function(){
                    $('#example').animate({width:function(){
                            console.log($(this).width());
                            return $(this).width()=="0"? "100":"0";
                    }});
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="example">            

        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Css" id="check"/>
        <input type="button" value="Animate" id="animate"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/72V8k/2/)

```
$('#animate').click(function () {
    $('#example').animate({
        width: (function ($self) {
            console.log($self.width());
            return $self.width() == "0" ? "100" : "0";
        })($('#example'))
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot and cant we write the function same as its in css ?

Comment: No because object is not passed as param of function animate ('this' refers to window)

Comment: you could use overflow:hidden property of container: http://jsfiddle.net/72V8k/5/

Comment: overflow:hidden is working properly but if our inner content exceeds the height or width it will be hided so I gave overflow:auto but I am facing the problem on re-sizing the div again [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/72V8k/6/)