# anonymous function in jquery animate() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

```
skillsDiv.css({
            'height':function(){
                return windowHeight - skillsHeightWithoutDiv
            }
        })
```

this code exactly returns what I want. it updates css style of en element

but when I do the samething in animate(), animate doesn't want to trigger

```
        $('#Skills>div').animate({
            height:function(){
                 //windowHeight - ($('#Skills').outerHeight - skillsDiv.outerHeight());
                 return '500px'
            }
        },1000);
```

this code never triggers, just never. I mean height in style attribute of $('#Skills>div') never becomes 
500px.

But when I remove function and set '500px' directly as value of height, animate() triggers.

What is wrong with my function ?

$('#Skills>div') is equal to skillsDiv in my code.

Comment: does animate allow properties that are functions? according to documentation, it's `An object of CSS properties and values that the animation will move toward.` - no mention of functions

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't know actually, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232179/writing-anonymous-function-in-jquery-animation I saw an answer that I can use  function... and I thought it should allow it becuz css() allows that

Comment: `$('#Skills').outerHeight - skillsDiv.outerHeight()` ????

Comment: in the answer on that question, the function is an IIFE ... so it would be `height: (function(){
                 return '500px'
            })()` in your case ... but the function is called exactly once - in essence, height will get a string value, once, that won't change - which is probably what you want anyway

Comment: @epascarello you see, that's just comment, so ignore that

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for help, I upvoted all your comments

Comment: To be fair, this question is really a duplicate of the post you've already read. You probably just didn't understand the IIFE in the answer?

Comment: @JaromandaX honestly, here is now 01:20 AM and I didn't realise that it was IIFE until you mentioned that in comment, css bugs are driving me crazy